# How to pass a variable value from the code behind to an external JavaScript file (jQuery file)?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Suppose I have this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename" ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'  OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click"> </asp:LinkButton>
```

How can I pass the `<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>` to an external JavaScript (jQuery) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of html tage data-id to do this.

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename"
 ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'
 CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' 
 OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" data-id='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' >
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

and in Jquery you can get that value as

```
var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Let me try this.

Comment: Hi I tried it and I know it should work. But for some reason it not. I believe it's because of the way I convert the address. For example filepath = "d:\folder\image.jpg" In my Jquery file I try to change it this way 
var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");
result = result.replace("D:\\", "http://wwwsite/VirtualDrive/");
result = result.replace("\\", "/");

Comment: Add I'm editing my JQuery file directly from Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Please let me know whatever your advice.

Comment: I could'nt understand what you really want to do with address that you are getting from data-id ? Could you plz elaborate this so that I can get the point you want to get ?

Comment: The way of storing your file path is not good i think.
filepath = "d:\folder\image.jpg" 
this way of storing image path is not quite good. you must save virtual path for any image

Comment: I already setup a virtual drive that's the reason why I need to replace get the filepath.
What I really want to do is to get the filepath and convert it from let say the value of the filepath is "d:\folder\img.jpg". Using my external jquery file I'm going to replace it from "d:\folder\img.jpg" to "d:\\folder\\img.jpg" then replace it to "http://ip/VDrive/folder/img.jpg".

Comment: try this code

var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");
result = result.replace("d:\folder\","ip/VDrive/folder/");

Answer (score 0):

Is this what it is you need ?

**HTML**

```
   var valueLink = document.getElementById('grdlinkFilename').innerText
```

**ASP**

```
   var valueLink = document.getElementById('<%=grdlinkFilename.ClientID %>').innerText
```

Comment: What is the output of this code is it the value of "filepath"?

Comment: this example, you should just return the value 'Filepath' attribute text. It should work. Have you tried?

Comment: I have an external javascript(jquery) file. What I want to do is to pass the value of <%#Eval("FILEPATH")% to my external js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using different state management available in ASP.NET and out of it. 
For ASP.NET "specific" state management , can have a look on good description on :

[A Beginner's Tutorial on ASP.NET State Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management)

Or, simply assign value to some UI element with `display:none`,and read it's value from `javascript`.